# Unable to install magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

Got a new company laptop and tried to install tidyr or installr, but it always fails because of magrittr.

If I want to install this package directly I'm getting the following error code:

```
* installing *source* package 'magrittr' ...
** package 'magrittr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="magrittr.dll" OBJECTS="pipe.o utils.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'magrittr'
* removing 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/magrittr'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpMHlNI9/downloaded_packages/magrittr_2.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't have admin privileges on this computer and could imagine that this could be the source of the problem, but I'm not sure.

What I tried:

- Changed folder for libraries
- Reinstalled all libraries
- Tried different cron repos
- Tried to install it on this way: `install.packages("magrittr", update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE))`

Always the same error.

Is there any other way to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing an archived version from source will work.

```
install.packages("cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/magrittr/…", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize conda to install it:

> conda install -c r r-magrittr

Reference:

1. https://anaconda.org/r/r-magrittr